# Is it possible to make a network drive show up as a folder?

Tags: windows-vista, network-share, directory

I'm using an online backup solution that does not work with networked drives or mapped drives. Is it possible to make a network drive show up as a "regular" folder? What possible impacts could this have?

**Edit:** The backup solution will backup files located here:

c:\SharedFolder

but not via net use command, such as:

F:\

I'm interested in do doing this in Windows Vista (and pretty soon in Windows 7).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft added [Symlink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) support in Windows Vista, which should work here. You'll need to use the `mklink` command line tool to do this:

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

/D - Creates a directory symbolic link. Default to file symbolic link.
/H - Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
/J - Creates a Directory Junction.
Link - Specifies the new symbolic link name.
Target - Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link refers to.
```

In your case, it'd work like this (assuming `Z:` is your mapped drive):

```
C:\> mklink /D C:\SharedFolder Z:
```

Then you should be able to point your backup software to `C:\SharedFolder`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a [symbolic link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Does it not work because it is a network drive, or because it doesn't have a drive letter/path?

If it's the second, just map the network drive to a drive letter.

Comment: The command line for that is net use z: \\server\share.

Comment: It doesn't work for mapped drives.